# How to create a single page checkout for donations but standard cart/checkout for for other ecommerce?

Tags: commerce

I am currently using Commerce for handling selling physical products but also donations.

I would like to have a one page donation that includes the amount and entering their credit card information but still allow the standard cart/checkout process if they are doing physical products.

Is there any way of doing both because it seems that I can only pull off one or the other?

[Here is an example](https://secure2.convio.net/cco/site/Donation2?df_id=24120&24120.donation=form1&s_src=DaffodilMonth2014_cancer.ca&s_subsrc=DMCTA_button_Donate&utm_source=Cancer.ca&utm_medium=DMCTA_Button_Donate&utm_campaign=DaffodilMonth2014) of a single page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Commerce Buy One Click](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_buy_one_click) module.

The Project page says

> Commerce Buy One Click Module allows customers to checkout directly
> from the product page with just one click, skipping the annoying
> checkout steps.

For more info go through the module documentation.

Comment: It appears that this is the closest I am going to get to a one-page checkout with the current state of Commerce. I wanted to have everything on one page, but this will have to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider donation and product buying are different task.

If user go for donations, call one step checkout form  by redirecting it to payment gateway and allow user to add his credit/debit card details to process it.

And if user go for purchasing physical product call standard checkout process.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can [commerce_express_checkout](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_express_checkout) for your case.
Maybe you will need in some additional modules with commerce_express_checkout

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try/experiment with the [Commerce Donate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_donate) module. Excerpt from its project page:

> provides a donation line item type along with a donation product and product display.
>
> In addition to being able to create a donation product, this module also provides a donation checkout pane, allowing customers to add a donation to their order as part of the checkout process.

**Note**: refer to [this tutorial/screencast](http://commerceguys.com/blog/using-custom-line-items-provide-donation-feature-drupal-commerce) also for a great introduction to this module.